# Разница между invokevirtual & invokespecial?

Tags: java, jvm

Правильно ли я поняла разницу между двумя инструкциями?

- `invokevirtual` применяется для вызова методов объекта и в качестве параметра в стек помещается ссылка на объект-владелец класса (`aload i`).
- `invokespecial` применяется для инициализации класса и вызова приватных методов. В случае вызова приватных методов всегда в стек записывается ссылка на объект-владелец (`this`) командой `aload 0`.

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли, главное, что они по разному резольвят методы [invokevirtual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) против [invokespecial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial).